# Multilinguistic site with resources in MVC4

Tags: internationalization, asp.net-mvc-4

What is technically the best way to translate small pieces of text such as labels on a site?

- A Global_resources file containing all the labels that are used throughout the site?
- A database table connected to my cultures table (which holds the languages). this table would basically be the same as the resources file.
- Another solution?

Keep in mind that a non-technical user will be able to log in into a CMS and adjust content although not on the level of labels, etc.

It would be nice however if it was possible to change the labels outside of visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following post: [Localization/Globalization should be database driven or resource/web framework(ASP.NET) driven or something custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783112/localization-globalization-should-be-database-driven-or-resource-web-frameworka) I think you will find your answer there. 
I would also like to add that resource files are plain XML. And thus altering the text of a label or such doesn't require the knowledge and or privileges of a DBA or other persons that have access to the db. You can alter the value of the resource file to the new value.

```
<root>
<!-- code ommited -->
  <data name="PropertyValueRequired" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Can't be empty</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Comment: Didn't come across that post when searching. Thanks! I think using the global_resources method is the best option as it will hold content that doesn't really change. The content that does change (about and FAQ page for example) will be editable by the user with admin rights and will thus be stored in the database.